# PHP: mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"

Tags: php

I tried to make simple php script to backup databes using mysqldump but i got this error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"
```

And this is the function that i have write to make the job:

```
 protected function dump($params, $dbs, $backup_folder)
    {
        if (!is_writable($backup_folder)) {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('The backup folder is not writable: %s',
                                        $backup_folder));
        }

        $backup_folder = trim($backup_folder, "/"); // be sure that there is no / at the end

        $baseCmd = 'mysqldump --hex-blob --routines --skip-lock-tables -h%s -u%s -p%s %s > %s';
        foreach ($dbs as $db) {
            $dest = sprintf('%s/%s', $backup_folder,
                            $db . '_' . date('YmdHis') . '.sql');
            $cmd = sprintf($baseCmd, $params['host'], $params['user'],
                           $params['password'], $db, $dest);
            echo "Exec: $cmd: ";

            $last = system(escapeshellcmd($cmd), $res);

            echo $res;

            if ( 0 !== $res) {
                echo "Fail";
            } else {
                echo "Done \n";
            }
        }
    }
```

The command printed by this function give:

```
mysqldump --hex-blob --routines --skip-lock-tables -hdb-backup -uroot -pMyPwd my_db_name > backups/my_db_name_20151010232734.sql
```

When i execute this command from Shell it works very well but not from Php script.

**My config is:**

- My Desktop System Shell: Ubuntu 15.04
- Mysql Server: Mysql 5.6 installed in Ubuntu Server 15.04
- PHP version: 5.6.4

Any help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `escapeshellcmd()` command prepends a `\` to the `>`.

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd):

> Following characters are preceded by a backslash: #&;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$\, \x0A and \xFF.

You should either escape each argument individually with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg), or ensure that your method arguments (`$params`, `$db`, and `$backup_folder`) are valid and don't contain one of those chars and just use

```
system($cmd, $res)
```

I hope this helps!